# How to set default value when disabled input is true

Tags: reactjs

I write a small app for user edit information, when disabled input == false, input is open and user can write information, and if disabled == true, value in input is default value (value before user edit). My app look like that.

```
const List = (props) => (
  <div className="list">
    { props.data.length > 0 && props.data.map((item,index) =>
      <div style={{ marginTop: '10px'}}>
        <input 
          type="text" 
          defaultValue={item.text}
          disabled={props.copyData[index]}
        />
        <button onClick={() => props.toggle(index)}> Click to toggle 
        </button>
      </div>
    )}        
  </div>
);

class App extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
         data: [
           {text: 'Some text 1'},
           {text: 'Some text 2'},
           {text: 'Some text 3'},
         ],
        copyData: [false,false,false]
     };
   }


   toggle = (index) => {
     let temp = this.state.copyData.slice();
     temp[index] = temp[index] ? false : true;
     this.setState({ copyData: temp });
   }

   render() {
     const { data, copyData } = this.state;
     return(
       <div className="App">
         <List data={data} copyData={copyData} toggle={this.toggle} />
       </div>
     );

   }
  }
```

Sorry for my bad english, Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
defaultValue={props.copyData[index] ? item.text || ''}
```